# Physical switch for LED light strip

Tags: lighting, smart-switch

I installed a Philips Hue RGB light strip in my home ([this model](https://www.philips-hue.com/en-us/p/hue-white-and-color-ambiance-lightstrip-plus-base-v4-80-inch/046677555337)). It plugs into a regular wall outlet and I turn it on and off using the Google Home app on my phone.

I would like to have a physical switch in the room which could also toggle the light strip. However I don't want the switch to interfere with Google Home's ability to toggle the lights. In other words, Google Home should be able to turn the lights on even if the switch is off. Is this achievable?

Comment: Do you want the automation to be able to turn the strip off even if you have it turned on manually?

Comment: Does the switch need to work when google is broken?  when the internet is down?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel yes

Comment: @Jasen preferably but it's not crucial

Comment: A 3-way switch where one end is controlled by Google.  Interesting idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Phillips (and others) makes switches for the Hue screw-in light bulbs, which I believe also work with light strips. [See the Phillips website.](https://www.philips-hue.com/en-us/explore-hue/works-with/smart-switches)

I've found it is undesirable to use a physical switch that disconnects power to the Hue light, as the light will revert to default settings when power is restored.

Comment: Using one of the Philips smart switches (or remotes) is probably the only way to do this easily. If you wire a regular switch to the receptacle serving the LED strip, Google Home can't turn the LED strip back on since power has been disconnected from the receptacle

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I wanted to buy a switch from another company, how would I know if it's compatible? Some of the ones Philips sells require their Bridge device which I'm trying to avoid due to cost

Comment: Can I just use any old smart switch, or do some function more like physical switches that disconnect the power?

Comment: Most smart switches do not disconnect the power, they usually send a signal to turn on and off. However that signal needs to be compatible with your light. I think the hue bulbs I have support the ZigBee protocol which is somewhat standard but I would still look for a hue approved switch on the link above. For your situation, I would choose the RunLessWire switch, it mounts anywhere and doesn't even need batteries. If you want to replace a legacy standard light switch, the Lutron Aurora is better. Also for some applications you need a Hue Hub. Not sure if a switch would require that.